# alternative to smb.conf / normal samba configuration

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, nfs, server-message-block

I have a Ubuntu-based server that provides SMB access for many users. Is there any way I could manage the shares and user permissions WITHOUT having to update smb.conf everytime? I'm not using LDAP in this setup either.

It's not a matter of me having to edit smb.conf, it's a matter of trying to automate the process. I have a custom web application which allows users of this application to create, modify, and delete Samba shares and users. However, the current way this is implemented involves the use of many scripts that automatically modify smb.conf as needed.

I'm thinking there has to be a better way. If not, is there a good alternative to Samba that could provide the same SMB service?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of storage management API? Do you definitely need SMB or alternatives like WebDAV would suffice?

Comment: some type of management API would be great, but it has to support the SMB protocol